# Can I make a UIScrollView only scroll when i interact only with specific places in the view? UIScrollView iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView wich contains 2 views the first at offset 0 and the other at offset 800.
I want the user to be able to scroll down but not always, because in the upper view i have another controls tha receive touch input and dragging and sometimes when you are dragging if your touch is just a little bit out of the control the scrollview scrolls and that's very annoying. So i want that the scrollview only scroll in certain zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically need is to subclass the UIView that should intercept touches outside it's frame and override it's hit test method.